# Search filter by Post title OR Meta Title Value

Tags: functions, theme-development, ajax, search

I am trying to search Movies by it's Post title OR Meta Title value.

But it is not working, it only search's by Meta value.

I need to search by Post title as well and ***i.e*** check if the keyword is there in title or not.

Please don't mark my question as duplicate, please look at my code and then please help me.

```
/* Live Search
     ========================================================
     */
     if( ! function_exists( 'dooplay_live_search' ) ) {
        function dooplay_live_search( $request_data ) {
              $parameters = $request_data->get_params();
            $keyword    = dt_clear($parameters['keyword']);
            $nonce      = dt_clear($parameters['nonce']);
           $types      = array('movies','tvshows');
           if( !dooplay_verify_nonce('dooplay-search-nonce', $nonce ) ) return array('error' => 'no_verify_nonce', 'title' => __d('No data nonce') );
           if( !isset( $keyword ) || empty($keyword) ) return array('error' => 'no_parameter_given');
           if( strlen( $keyword ) <= 2 ) return array('error' => 'keyword_not_long_enough', 'title' => false );

           $meta_query = array();
           $args = array();
           $search_string =  "test";



           $meta_query[] = array(
              'key' => 'original_title',
              'value' => $keyword,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
           );

           $meta_query[] = array(
              'key' => 'original_name',
              'value' => $keyword,
              'compare' => 'LIKE'
           );

           //if there is more than one meta query 'or' them
           if(count($meta_query) > 1) {
              $meta_query['relation'] = 'OR';
           }

           // The Query
           $args['post_type'] = $types;
           $args['_meta_or_title'] = $search_string; //not using 's' anymore
           $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
              $data = array();
                while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    $query->the_post();
                    global $post;
                    $data[$post->ID]['title'] = $post->post_title;
                    $data[$post->ID]['url'] = get_the_permalink();
                 if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    $data[$post->ID]['img'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'dt_poster_b');
                 } elseif ($dato = dt_get_meta('dt_poster')) {
                    $data[$post->ID]['img'] = dt_image_search('dt_poster', $post->ID, 'w92', false, true );
                 } else {
                    $data[$post->ID]['img'] = esc_url( DOO_URI ) . '/assets/img/no/poster-small.png';
                 }
                 if($dato = dt_get_meta('release_date')) {
                    $data[$post->ID]['extra']['date'] = substr($dato, 0, 4);
                 }
                 if($dato = dt_get_meta('first_air_date')) {
                    $data[$post->ID]['extra']['date'] = substr($dato, 0, 4);
                 }
                 $data[$post->ID]['extra']['imdb'] = dt_get_meta('imdbRating');
                }
                return $data;
            } else {
              return array('error' => 'no_posts', 'title' => __d('No results') );
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }
     }
```

Comment: @nmr Please check the question properly and please help with my code instead of adding it to duplicate. Please!

Comment: The question is the same, so it is a duplicate. You please look at the existing question and answers. Everything you need is there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have not changed the operator in the function attached to the `get_meta_sql` filter.
If `$search_string` is only fragment of the title, you should change `post_title = '%s'` in code from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/178484/wp-query-args-title-or-meta-value) answer to:

```
$sql['where'] = sprintf(" AND ( %s OR %s ) ",
        // --- post title begins with the searched phrase --
        $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%s'", $title . '%' ),
        // -- OR post title contains the searched phrase --
        // $wpdb->prepare( "{$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%s'", '%'. $title . '%' ),
        mb_substr( $sql['where'], 5, mb_strlen( $sql['where'] ) )
);
```