# Can I change the default search behavior "OR search" to "AND search"?

Tags: search

For example, if I search the site with the following parameters.
`http://localhost/?s=KEYWORD&tag[]=TAG1&tag[]=TAG2`

This is like saying that `Posts where [keyword is 'KEYWORD'] OR [has 'TAG1' tag] OR [has 'TAG2' tag]`.

So this is an "OR search", I don't want that, I want "AND search". 
How can I change this default behavior??

Comment: Ajax search lite is the best search plugin for WP. It supports your required functionality. Replacing the default WordPress search requires you to write a plugin yourself - and don't modify the core. See this page from the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Search_Page

Answer (score 0):

The default is **"AND search"** but not *"OR search"*.

We can see that [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/8cfdf4dd3a282d58ca524eec742779f3ec708f65/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L1365) in the `WP_Query::parse_search()` method:

```
if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
    $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
```

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/174221/26350) I've posted a hack, some time ago, to get the *OR* version.